# Swift: Cannot invoke 'addSubview' with an argument list of type '(UIRefreshControl!)'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a pull to refresh in my UITableView with Swift 2. I have added this just below my class declaration:

```
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
```

And this in my viewDidLoad()

```
self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
```

However, that last line is giving the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'addSubview' with an argument list of type '(UIRefreshControl!)'

What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this?

Screenshot of my code:

[image: Code screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is `tableView` ? I see only `appsTableView` in your code

Comment: @nRewik, refreshControl is a property of UITableView**Controller**, not UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

You should not add subviews directly to a table view. You should treat it's view hierarchy as private, and only manipulate it using it's public interface. If you want a refresh control that is handled by the system you should probably be using a `UITableViewController` and installing your refresh control in it's `refreshControl` property.